# how to do svn labeling.(modified)

Tags: svn

I am working on linux enviournment and currently i am using svn's branch for developement purpose...but now i have to delete it and i have to work with main brach with today's date as a lebel like ..suppose my svn repostiory is "xyz" so now i want it to be like "xyz_production_lastproductionDate" than how to label it.Please share your opinion as i got stuck because of this...
                              Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you want to know ?  What sort of labels do you want to attach to what sort of objects ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create a tag. Since svn does not have distinguished handling for tags and branches, the typical workflow is to copy the desired svn directory into the tags/ folder (example: `svn cp file:///path/to/my/repo/branches/xyz@23 file:///path/to/my/repo/tags/xyz_production_lastproductionDate`)

.